# How to Connect EntityFramework Core to Multiple Google CloudSQL Instances Using CloudSQL Proxy?

Tags: entity-framework, kubernetes, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I have 2 Postgres databases each in their own CloudSQL instance and a .NET web app running in GKE.

Goal: Connect web app utilizing EntityFramework Core to both CloudSQL instances using a single CloudSQL proxy.

I followed [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-engine-samples/blob/master/cloudsql/postgres_deployment.yaml) setup and modified it following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40793222/connecting-to-multiple-cloudsql-instances-using-cloud-sql-proxy) S.O. answer.

There is an EF Core DbContext for each CloudSQL Instance.
The context connections are set using 2 environment variables:

```
new Context1(
{
optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CONNECTION_1"));
});

new Context2(
{
optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CONNECTION_2"));
});
```

The environment variables are set as:

```
CONNECTION_1 = "Host=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=password"

CONNECTION_2 = "Host=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=password2"
```

**Current Behavior:**

Context1 interacts with CloudSQL instance1 as normal.

Context2 throws PostgresException `"42P01: relation {my_Table_Name} does not exist."` when trying to access a table.

Note: `"my_Table_Name"` is a table in CloudSQL instance2

This leads me to believe Context2 is trying to access CloudSQL instance1 instead of instance2.

How can I point Context2 through the SQL Proxy to CloudSQL instance2?

Answer (score 1):

Basically this:

> ```
> CONNECTION_1 = "Host=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=password"
> CONNECTION_2 = "Host=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=password2"
> ```

means that you are connecting to the exact same Cloud SQL instance, with just two different passwords (same username). Not sure how CONNECTION_2 might even connect to the Cloud SQL instance1 though.

You would want to have something like this:

> ```
> CONNECTION_1 = "Host=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=password"
> CONNECTION_2 = "Host=127.0.0.1;Port=5433;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=password2"
> ```

and on your cloud-proxy command line (running on the same pod):

```
-instances=project:region:sqlinstance1=tcp:5432,project:region:sqlinstance2=tcp:5433
```

Comment: Matching the ports to those defined in the deployment.yaml didn't work either. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try shelling into the pod and debug from there

Comment: @msauce4 did Cloud SQL Proxy worked for you in the end?